# Embeddings of linear orders in $\wp(\omega)/Fin$ under Martin's axiom

Tags: set-theory

We know that, under MA, every linear order $(X,\le)$ with $|X|<\mathfrak c$ embedds in $\wp(\omega)/Fin$. Does this hold for linear orders with cardinality $\mathfrak c$?

Comment: Is it obvious even that a well-ordering of size $\mathfrak{c}$ consistently embeds into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/Fin$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yes, Take (for example) a $\leq^\star$-increasing sequence of reals of length continuum, $\langle f_\alpha \mid \alpha < 2^\omega\rangle$, $f_\alpha \in \omega^\omega$, and define $x_\alpha = \{(n,m) \in \omega \times \omega \mid n \leq f(m)\}$. Then $x_\alpha$ are increasing modulo finite errors.

Comment: @YairHayut Why must such a sequence exist?

Comment: @DouglasUlrich I think that since $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{c}$ under MA, any maximal, well ordered $\leq^\star$-increasing sequence will have length continuum. Also, one can use directly the fact that the tower number $\mathfrak{t}$ is continuum under MA to get an increasing (mod finite) sequence of subsets of $\omega$ of length continuum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually independent of $MA+\neg CH$.

For example, under $MA+OCA$ there are no gaps in $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ of type $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c}^\ast)$, which excludes the possibility that every linear order of size $\mathfrak{c}$ embeds. This is because assuming $MA$, the linear order $L=(2^{<\mathfrak{c}}, <_\text{lex})$ has size $\mathfrak{c}$ and $2^{\mathfrak{c}}>\mathfrak{c}$ gaps of type $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c}^\ast)$; hence any embedding of $L$ into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$ witnesses the existence of a gap of type $(\mathfrak{c}, \mathfrak{c}^\ast)$ in $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$.

That said, the consistency of $MA+$"every linear order of size $\mathfrak{c}$ embeds into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$" is attributed to H. Woodin 
(see this question "[$\mathfrak{c}$-universal linear order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91027/mathfrakc-universal-linear-order)")

To construct such a model, you use the following two facts,

- Any $c.c.c.$ forcing which adds a generic gap of type $(\omega_1, \omega_1^{\ast})$ to a *ground-model* linear order adds an $\omega_1$-branch to some *ground-model* Souslin-tree.
- The partial order which specializes a Souslin-tree with finite conditions does not add a branch to any ground-model $\omega_1$-tree.

and construct an iteration which interleaves Souslin-free forcings with those that split gaps in the $\mathfrak{c}$-universal linear order you are building.